# View position glitches around in scroll view when scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, debugging, uiscrollview

Whenever you scroll, the title view bugs out and rapidly switches between two positions.  The label manages to stay within the constraints of the view, and it is just the view's position that bugs.

I've made a gif of the issue if it is still unclear or you need to see an example of the problem.

https://gph.is/g/EJ09l9Z

I've tried playing around with constraints to no avail.  I still believe that the issue is to do with constraints, although I am not an expert by any means in Xcode or swift so I could be wildly wrong.

These are the constraints that I have been working with and around in attempts to get this working.

```
titleView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
titleView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentView.topAnchor, constant: 6).isActive = true
titleView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentView.rightAnchor, constant: 6).isActive = true
titleView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: timeView.topAnchor).isActive = true

titleLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleView.leftAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleView.topAnchor).isActive = true
titleLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
titleLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: timeView.topAnchor).isActive = true
titleLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

The goal is for the title to stay in the one position as the view is scrolled, like the labels and views beneath it.  Feel free to suggest any other fixes or ask for more code, I just don't know what the problem would be if not constraints.

Also for clarification, I am not using a UIScrollView, but rather an OLEContainerScrollView.
https://github.com/ole/OLEContainerScrollView
https://oleb.net/blog/2014/05/scrollviews-inside-scrollviews/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It's not at all clear what you're trying to do, or why you're not simply using a standard `UIScrollView`. Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: @DonMag Sorry for not clarifying the reason.  I am using the OLEContainerScrollView because when using the regular UIScrollView I was having trouble getting the UITableView of the comments (at the bottom, seen in the gif) to work as needed.  I don't know how I can explain what I am trying to do more clearly, as it's difficult to explain but the gif should be clear about what the issue is. Thanks in advance for any help.